# How can I calculate delta at dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, delta

```
A   B   C   Delta
**1 Jan 10  0**
1   Feb 20  10
1   Mar 40  30
**2 Jan 10  0**
2   Feb 30  20
2   Mar 20  10
2   Oct 40  30
**3 Jan 10  0**
3   Feb 20  10
3   Mar 30  20
3   Oct 40  30
3   Dec 50  40
```

how can I calculate delta column?

I couldn't find it anywhere. 
Please let me know. how to calculate

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? Is delta just the values of column C subtract 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract column `C` by [`Series.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html) with repeated first values per groups by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
df['Delta'] = df['C'].sub(df.groupby('A')['C'].transform('first'))
print (df)
    A    B   C  Delta
0   1  Jan  10      0
1   1  Feb  20     10
2   1  Mar  40     30
3   2  Jan  10      0
4   2  Feb  30     20
5   2  Mar  20     10
6   2  Oct  40     30
7   3  Jan  10      0
8   3  Feb  20     10
9   3  Mar  30     20
10  3  Oct  40     30
11  3  Dec  50     40
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.groupby('A')['C'].transform('first'))
0     10
1     10
2     10
3     10
4     10
5     10
6     10
7     10
8     10
9     10
10    10
11    10
Name: C, dtype: int64
```